# Loading dependencies other than by relative path?

Tags: typescript

I'm working in a build system which is... different.

- It runs tools like compilers in parallel on remote machines.
- We keep dependencies in a common place for all users, rather than copying a lib/ directory or similar under each project's source root.
- We check out only a subset of the repository to each developers machine, which means some files are on local disk and some are accessed in a FUSE filesystem.
- Some inputs (eg. `.d.ts` files) are generated by the build system and these are in a different path or loaded from yet another FUSE filesystem.

So I end up with things like

```
// hmm, is this the right number of ..'s to 
// get up to the shared DefinitelyTyped repo?
/// <reference path='../../../../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts' />
```

and a lot of code shuffling files around inside the build system to lay out a file structure mimicking what tsc expects.

These problems are due to relying exclusively on the tsc behavior of resolving `/// <reference/>` tags relative to the path of the file in which it appears. What I would really like is to give a stack of absolute paths which should be resolved by checking in order:

1. Root path in the developers working space
2. Root path where build system puts generated files
3. Root path of the readonly snapshot of the entire repository

Does anyone have a workaround for loading files a different way (like a custom compiler frontend on top of the language services API?)
Has the core TS team considered a feature like this?

Comment: Looking at the source code of the `tsc` compiler it seems that you can use rooted paths (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tryresolvescriptreference&type=Code) already. Can you shorten your problem into some [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have a workaround for loading files a different way

You can use `grunt-ts` transforms to resolve the relative path issues for you : https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#transforms

> (like a custom compiler frontend on top of the language services API?)

Atom-TypeScript has a compilation context determined from `tsconfig.json` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md so you don't need to *reference* files. But you will still need to *import* them for external modules. I am working on making it easier to generate these for you (one of the reasons I created atomts).

Comment: Awesome 1.4.1 supported :)

Comment: I'm even thinking of moving to master builds from github as it contains fixes to stuff I and others raised